# Deploying Jenkins within Glassfish throw Exception

Tags: java, glassfish, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy Jenkins 1.432 to GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 (build 12), running in Ubuntu 10.04.
It throws this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Installation Problem???  Couldn't load messages: Can't find bundle for base name com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.message, locale en_US
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegexParser.setLocale(RegexParser.java:93)

The **locale** ubuntu command returns:

> LANG=en_US.UTF-8

I don't know what to do. I googled many thing, without really founding something. Classpath problem ? Right permission ? Missing jar in jvm ?

Answer (score 0):

I finaly decided to deploy Jenkins outside Glassfish, with the debian package.
I guess my Glassfish install is missing a language package (?), but I am not sure.